# Lotus Notes Designer 8.5.3 , Cannot see Web Services in the code section?

Tags: lotus

I cannot see the option to create a web service provider or consumer in Notes 8.5.3

I can goto the "Code" options menu in designer, but i do not see the option "Web Service Providers".

Any ideas ? I find this very weird, I did a reinstall and still nothing !

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other perspectives remove the webservices from the outline (eg. XPages). Go to "Window -> Open Perspective -> Domino Designer".

If that doesn't bring it back, try doing a reset perspective.

Comment: If the answer from Simon doesn't help, then see if the design elements have been removed from the Applications Navigator by going to File - Preferences, and check the design elements in the Domino Designer - Applications Navigator section.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. Simon... It worked.... I did the reset and it did not work, but Window -> Open Perspective -> Domino Designer, did the trick....