# XPages Missing in Designer 8.5.3?

Tags: xpages

I'm really curious to know what could be the reason for "xapges disappearing from Designer 8.5.3"??

I don't know whether it b'cz of missing plugin or something else... bt wanted to knw the possible reasons.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to switch your "Perspective" under Windows menu.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457890/lotus-notes-designer-8-5-3-cannot-see-web-services-in-the-code-section/12458249#12458249

Comment: oh yeah....Thanks Much ..... it worked Thanks again Frantisek & Simon

Comment: Can we start putting these suggestions in answers instead of comments so that these questions stop showing up as unanswered, please?

Comment: @Vic Stackoverflow automatically puts it into a comment if all you post is a URL. I flagged it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment by Frantisek....

Domino 8.5.3 introduces three separate Perspectives Forms/View used for Notes Client development, XPages for XPages development and the Domino Designer perspective used for a mixture of Notes CLient and Xpages development. These perspectives limit the amount of views included and the design elements displayed to those relevant for each style of development.